# How to send the photo in base64 and other data in json?

Tags: json, parameters, request, base64, alamofire

I need to send in this format json:

```
{ "DocCont":[{ "DocumentContent":"base64 string", "LeftEyeX":"String", "LeftEyeY":"String", "RightEyeX":"String", "RightEyeY":"String" }], "OrderId":"String", "Token":"String" }
```

I'm posting this is so:

```
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation((info[UIImagePickerControllerOrigin‌​alImage] as? UIImage)!) 
let imgBase64 = imageData!.base64EncodedString(options: [])

let param: Parameters = ["DocCont": [["DocumentContent": "(imgBase64)","LeftEyeX": "LeftEyeX","LeftEyeY": "LeftEyeY","RightEyeX": "RightEyeX","RightEyeY": "RightEyeY"]],"OrderId": "myOrder","Token": "myToken"]

let url = "OrderService.svc/SendScan"

Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success(let value):
        let json = JSON(value)
        print("Client error: \(json["Error"])")
        print("Client IsOK: \(json["IsOK"])")
    case .failure(let error):
        print("error send scans: \(error)")
    }
}
```

But I get the error "responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 3." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 3.}))"

it's shown me after `print("request: \(NSString(data: (response.request?.httpBody)!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))")` :

```
{ "DocCont":[{ "DocumentContent":"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QBYRXhpZ..."‌​, "LeftEyeX":"63", "LeftEyeY":"42", "RightEyeX":"23", "RightEyeY":"33" }], "OrderId":"52709", "Token":"8A4FD140-993A-47D8-9F41-74CABE21F806" }
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: This `"(imgBase64)"` will be just string `(imgBase64)` in parameters array instead of actual base64 data. And even `"\(imgBase64)"` won't do what you want, because it would add `Optional(` before actual base64 string. So you need to get rid of optionality and properly put value of `imgBase64` into `param`.

Comment: @user28434
do not tell me how to do it?

Comment: I added the following line and make sure that the structure is correct json

'print("request: \(NSString(data: (response.request?.httpBody)!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))")'

what else can be wrong?

Comment: and what does it prints? Also try to use `Swift` types (`String` instead of `NSString`, `Data` instead of `NSData`).

Comment: @user28434 it prints: "responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 3." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 3.}))"

Comment: Can you add this to the question, also add printout of `param` dictionary. Also check `imageData` really must be optional, and you cannot use `if let` or `guard let` or something to unwrap it there.

Comment: @user28434 
'let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation((info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage)!)
        let imgBase64 = imageData!.base64EncodedString(options: [])'

Comment: @user28434 
it's shown me after 
`print("request: \(NSString(data: (response.request?.httpBody)!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))")` :
`{ "DocCont":[{ "DocumentContent":"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QBYRXhpZ...", "LeftEyeX":"63", "LeftEyeY":"42", "RightEyeX":"23", "RightEyeY":"33" }], "OrderId":"52709", "Token":"8A4FD140-993A-47D8-9F41-74CABE21F806" }`

Comment: **Add it to the question itself**. Click `edit` and add it in the question.